# How spark driver decides which spark executors are to be used?

Tags: apache-spark

How a spark driver program decides, which executors are to be used for a particular job?

***Is it Data locality Driven?***
    Are the executors chosen based on the availability of data on that datanode?  
If yes, what happens if all the data is present on a single data node and the data node has just enough resources to run 2 executors, but in the spark-submit command we have used ***--num-executors 4***. Which should run 4 executors?
Will spark driver copy some of the data from that datanode to some other datanode and spawn 2 more executors (out of the 4 required executors)?

Comment: Data Locality is gone with Cloud Computing.

Comment: @thebluephantom this is a *strong* postulate. Nevertheless, I partially agree with you. Cloud computing created new challenges concerning data locality.

Comment: @eliasah  Sure, I get the point, but many do not get that - they assume the MR paradigm.